# Domain redirection to specific page in IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, redirect

I have a website on IIS set to domain1.com. I also have a domain called domain2.com that is redirecting to domain1.com. I currently have this set up in the domain1.com bindings. I need to change this to where domain2.com is redirected to domain1.com/blog

Would I do this through the web.config file or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do it using the **appcmd.exe** command, using command prompt.
The above commands should do the job.
This commands are also useful to create any kind of redirection.
The [url rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module is a requirement. It has to be installed on your IIS.
This commands are running without problems on my Windows Server 2012 machine.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='Redirect_To_www',enabled='True']" >> output.out
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules -[name='Redirect_To_www'].match.url:"(.*)" >> output.out
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules -[name='Redirect_To_www'].match.ignoreCase:true >> output.out

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules -[name='Redirect_To_www'].conditions.logicalGrouping:"MatchAny" >> output.out
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='Redirect_To_www'].conditions.[input='{HTTP_HOST}',pattern='^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$',negate='true']" >> output.out

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules -[name='Redirect_To_www'].action.type:"Redirect" >> output.out
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules -[name='Redirect_To_www'].action.url:"http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" >> output.out
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules -[name='Redirect_To_www'].action.appendQueryString:true >> output.out
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%domain%" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules -[name='Redirect_To_www'].action.redirectType:"Permanent" >> output.out
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018818/iis7-url-redirection-from-root-to-sub-directory

Here it is. Add this code to your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/menu_1/MainScreen.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

It will do 301 Permanent Redirect (URL will be changed in browser). If you want to have such "redirect" to be invisible (rewrite, internal redirect), then use this rule (the only difference is that "Redirect" has been replaced by "Rewrite"):

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/menu_1/MainScreen.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Ok so I already have a rewrite rule in my web.config. Do I need to add everything between the <rewrite></rewrite> tags in your example to the rewrite rule that is already in my web.config file or will it work with two different <rewrite></rewrite> rules?

Comment: You would add each rule inside the `rules` section as `<rule name>` and end each with `</rule>` then end all of them with `</rewrite>` for all of your rewrite rules.